# Calculation between controls array using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating 2 dynamic controls array.

```
<input type=text name=quantity[]>
<input type=text name=price[]>
```

I want to multiply these two inputs and show the result accordingly. I want to do it on frontend using javascript or jQuery.

What will be the best possible way of doing it?

**EDIT**
@Zeus 
As I mentioned in the question it is an array of controls so the code will go like this

```
<input type="text" name="quantity[]"> <input type="text" name="price[]">
<input type="text" name="quantity[]"> <input type="text" name="price[]">
<input type="text" name="quantity[]"> <input type="text" name="price[]">
```

Now I will enter quantity in first textfield and price in the second one. For each row I need to multiply these fields and show the result next to them.

Hope it explains the question more.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: provide an example input and desired output.

Comment: @Zeus Question edited please check and see if I made it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this :

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("#calc tr").each(function(i) {   
    var result = $(this).find("input[name*='quantity[]']").val() * $(this).find("input[name*='price[]']").val();
    $(this).children("td:nth-child(3)").html(result);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="calc">
  <tr>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Result</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="quantity[]">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="price[]">
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="quantity[]">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="price[]">
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="quantity[]">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="price[]">
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button>Click me after entering values</button>
```

Run the code to test it.

This is just an example you will be needing to edit the code to make it work for you.